# Can anyone identify these Western Australian seeds?

Tags: identification, seeds

[image]

Can anyone identify these seeds collected in Western Australia. The main black part of the seed is around 5-6 mm in size.

Comment: would you be able to describe the plant by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bird of Paradise plant seeds; Strelitzia reginae in particular, image here http://www.vilmorin-tree-seeds.com/seeds/shrubs/entry-13120-strelitzia-reginae.html